# How to fix a button on a dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher, replacement

I have a [Bosch SHE44c05uc/20](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/bosch-button-425567-ap3857642.html#).

One of the buttons on the door doesn't pop back when pressed. I looked inside and found that one of the little plastic springs is broken. Looks like a $.25 part, but it comes with the control panel that costs $170 to replace and no way to buy separately. Any suggestions for a workaround?

[image]

Comment: We could probably offer better suggestions from an actual photograph.

Answer (score 4):

I had this happen on two different machines. I was able to just use some crazy glue on the one because I had the parts. The other occasion I was missing the parts so I took the spring from a switch on the machine that I never used.. I think it was the "quick rinse" button. If you can't swap out the spring maybe you can swap out the switch or swap the connections. Last but not least, if it's just a simple toggle switch pick up a small one from a home or electrical supply company, hook it up and mount it on the door.

Comment: I have repaired with a push button switch also I had room to mount it just below the controls it worked for a few years then something died so we replaced it.